# Why is my lookup field not allowing me to type into it?

Tags: visualforce, lookup, inputfield

I have a Visualforce page with a pageblock containing an Account lookup. All is fine so far.
[image]

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="pba" title="" collapsible="false">
<apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!AddCallCycleActivity.Account__c}" label="Add a new Account" required="false"/>
<apex:inputField id="NewAccTime" value="{!AddCallCycleActivity.MeetingTime__c}" label="Time of new Appointment" required="false"/>
<apex:inputCheckbox id="nonCRM" label="Include Non-CRM Contacts?" value="{!NonCRMContacts}"/>
<apex:inputCheckbox id="ActAllC" label="Add separate Appointments for ALL CRM Contacts for this Account" value="{!AllActContacts}"/>
<apex:inputText id="TimeInterval" label="Time Interval for Appointments(minutes)" value="{!ActTimeInterval}" maxlength="2" size="2" required="false"/>
```

I am wanting to add another lookup, but as soon as I do this, the format of the lookup for the Account changes. The only difference in the code is the additional inputField with the Contact. Can anyone tell me why? As soon as I remove the contact lookup it displays properly again. 
[image]

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="pba" title="" collapsible="false">
<apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!AddCallCycleActivity.Account__c}" label="Add a new Account" required="false"/>
<apex:inputField id="AcctContact" value="{!AddCallCycleActivity.Main_Contact__c}" label="Add a new Contact" required="false"/>
<apex:inputField id="NewAccTime" value="{!AddCallCycleActivity.MeetingTime__c}" label="Time of new Appointment" required="false"/>
<apex:inputCheckbox id="nonCRM" label="Include Non-CRM Contacts?" value="{!NonCRMContacts}"/>
<apex:inputCheckbox id="ActAllC" label="Add separate Appointments for ALL CRM Contacts for this Account" value="{!AllActContacts}"/>
<apex:inputText id="TimeInterval" label="Time Interval for Appointments(minutes)" value="{!ActTimeInterval}" maxlength="2" size="2" required="false"/>
```

Comment: do you have lookup filter on the contact?

Comment: Yes I do - is that what's causing this?

Comment: I think so, just remove the filter and see what happens?

Comment: I have put that in answer, please mark, so this will help to other members, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lookup filter on Contact and it depends on the Account, that's why Salesforce standard behavior allows the user to select first the Account and then Contact.

The screen is showing default behavior when both of the lookup fields available on the layout where Contact has lookup filter.

For more information, refer [Creating Lookup Filters ON Relationship Fields](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_filtered_lookups_cheatsheet.pdf)